# Adding an onclick function to go to url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am using this code to get URL from "button_url". and need onclick function will act as a link go to a URL in new tab. I don't get the URL on the button, why?

```
<?php $button_url = get_field('button_url'); ?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var button_url = '<?php echo $button_url; ?>';
$("#myBtn").attr("href", button_url);
});
</script>
```

The code in sidebar:

```
<a href="" id="myBtn">button</a>
```

Comment: Does `button_url` in the source have a value?

Comment: There is a field in that created in ACF plugin, called "button_url" where the value was entered.

Comment: Does `var button_url` have the value in the source?

Comment: No. That's the problem. I don't understand why the button doesn't get the value

Comment: I tried it exactly as you have it and got my href in the "a" element. The only bit I didn't have is the function "get_field", may I see that implementation and know where it is located?

Comment: how did you do that? How did you add the field? I use ACF. It does not work :(

Comment: If you don't get the value than `$button_url` isn't being set so see what `get_field('button_url')` is returning with `var_dump`.

Comment: What does that mean? Can you explain? How did it work for you? It doesn't work for me

Comment: I don't get the value, which is exactly the name of the field. so whats the problem?